# Catch clauses not catching right?

Tags: c++, exception

I'm just learning how to use exceptions in C++ and have come across weird behavior in my "test" code. (excuse overly stupid questions like this one, please...it's NOT lack of research/effort, just lack of experience!) If I'm catching just the exception `DivideByZero` it works fine.

But introducing the second exception `StupidQuestion` makes the code not work exactly how I expected. How I wrote it below I thought it should take care of the `DivideByZero` exception if it needs to, and if not then check if `StupidQuestion` occurs, and if not just go back to the `try` clause and print the normal result. But if I input, say, `a=3` and `b=1`, the program redirects to the `DivideByZero` `try` clause instead of the `StupidQuestion` one. The weird thing is, though, `divide` does seem to be throwing `StupidQuestion` (see via `cout` statement), but it's not catching right, as also seen by the absense of the `cout` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
const int DivideByZero = 42;
const int StupidQuestion=1337;
float divide (int,int);
main(){
       int a,b;
       float c;
       cout << "Enter numerator: ";
       cin >> a;
       cout << "Enter denominator: ";
       cin >> b;
       try{
           c = divide(a,b);
           cout << "The answer is " << c << endl;
           }
       catch(int DivideByZero){
                           cout << "ERROR: Divide by zero!" << endl;
                           }
       catch(int StupidQuestion){
                                 cout << "But doesn't come over here...?" << endl;
                             cout << "ERROR: You are an idiot for asking a stupid question like that!" << endl;
                             }
       system("PAUSE");
       }

float divide(int a, int b){
      if(b==0){
               throw DivideByZero;
               }
      else if(b==1){
               cout << "It goes correctly here...?" << endl;
               throw StupidQuestion;
               }
      else return (float)a/b;
}
```

I was wondering if it had something to do with the fact that `DivideByZero` and `StupidQuestion` were both of type `int`, so I changed the code to make StupidQuestion be of type char instead of int. (So: `const char StupidQuestion='F';` and `catch(char StupidQuestion)` were really the only things changed from above) And it worked fine.

Why isn't the above code working when the two exceptions have the same type (`int`)?

Comment: The exceptions are caught by type not by name.  So both are type int and the first handler is going to catch them.  If you want to differentiate them make the second one a different type.

Comment: @Duck: This would be the answer I'd upvote.

Comment: Any reason not to create classes that inherit from exception and use those instead? That follows the pattern better than throwing random types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this

```
catch(int DivideByZero) {
    cout << "ERROR: Divide by zero!" << endl;
}
catch(int StupidQuestion) {
    cout << "But doesn't come over here...?" << endl;
    cout << "ERROR: You are an idiot for asking a stupid question like that!" << endl;
}
```

you are looking for

```
catch (int errval) {
    if (errval == DivideByZero) {
        cout << "ERROR: Divide by zero!" << endl;
    }
    else if (errval == StupidQuestion) {
        cout << "ERROR: You are an idiot for asking a stupid question like that!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        throw; // for other errors, keep searching for a handler
    }
}
```

**The variable name inside the `catch` clause is creating a new local variable, which has no relation to a global constant with the same name.**

Also note that there will be no way to catch just one error number... but you can rethrow unknown errors as I show.

Answer (score 3):

```
catch(int DivideByZero)   { }
catch(int StupidQuestion) { }
```

Both `catch` blocks catch `int`s, they're just named differently. Only the first one can ever be entered, the second one is dead code.

Comment: What's the point of naming them (like I saw in the tutorial) if they only do by type? Then I would have to declare/use a new type for every  catch clause??? which seems kind of long winded...

Comment: @Thornshadow17432: Link the tutorial, we need more context for this.

Comment: @Thornshadow17432 its like calling a function. it passes the value to you and it is stored in that variable so you can use it in the block. such as `catch( string ex ){ cerr << ex << endl; }`

Comment: The point of naming them is so that you can refer to them by name, just as is the point of naming any other variable in your program. That's especially important since, as you've now learned, we catch things by type, not by specific value. Multiple distinct exceptions can all have different values but the same type. You'll want to read their values to determine details about them. This becomes more valuable when you start throwing *classes* since you get to use inheritance to catch objects of many related types.

Comment: @Thornshadow17432 “which seems kind of long winded” – but it’s not in practice. It turns out that you don’t need terribly many different exception types, it’s mostly the same ones recurring.

Comment: @Thornshadow17432 Just to be clear, it's not the catch clause that's being named. It's the variable that's being named.

Answer (score 0):

When choosing a handler for an exception only type is taken into account, and neither values nor addresses (addresses of variables are not applicable here at all because of how exceptions work), also names of variables do not exist after compilation.
The first appropriate handler for the exception is always chosen.

Please look my answer to another question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45436594/1790694