# Throwing an error to main from a function called by another function

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

Let's say I have a function (`mnHw`) that calculates the mean of a vector (a vector of homework grades). This function throws a `domain_error("Student did no homework")` exception when the vector is empty. When I call `mnHw` from `main`, things are simple when I want to print out the error:

```
        try
        {
            cout  <<  mnHw(student.homework);
        }
        catch (domain_error e)
        {
            cout << e.what();
        }
```

However, things are complicated if I only want to store the mean homework grade, instead of vector of all grades, for the student. In that case I call `mnHw` within the function that reads in the student information (`readStudent`), and put up a flag (-1) when no homework is entered:

```
        try
        {
            student.finalGrade=mnHw(hwGrades);
        }
        catch (domain_error e)
        {
            student.finalGrade = -1;
        }
```

Then, within `main`, I can do the following to recover the error:

```
    if (allStudents[i].finalGrade == -1) 
        cout << "Student did no homework";
    else  
        cout << allStudents[i].finalGrade;
```

Intuitively, though, this flag method seems less elegant than having the actual error message pass directly to main, at least for those cases when I want to display it from main (which is the case here). Is there some trick or technique I am missing that would directly give `main` access to `e.what()` from `mnHw`?

What is good practice?

Note I have full functions for each of these cases that I could post, but they seemed too long. Please let me know if I should have included them to make myself more clear. Also, please feel free to correct any other mistakes I’m making. I am just now learning C++ the right way, and want to be corrected as much as possible. `<flame-retardant vest>`

Comment: "this flag method seems less elegant than having the actual error message pass directly to main" - not quite. Personally, I hate functions that are supposed to do computations, but they are printing to stdout/stderr. It hurts my sense of balance. :P If a function is doing computation, then let it do its task then return either a valid value, or an out-of-range value in order to signal an error. Then its user/client/caller (think of your code as if it was going to be a library!) can do whatever it wants to when it encounters an error.

Comment: Why not let your funcion throw the exception and do the catch on `main`?

Comment: @wesley.mesquita: that's what the first version does (the first block of code in my original post is from main). But the question is, how do I do this in main when the exception-throwing function is called by another function? Note this is part of my self-study of problem 4.6 of **Accelerated C++**. I think the main point of this question is to figure out this puzzle. My "solution" is to use a flag, but I can't help but think there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-throw the exception catched `(const domain_error* e){ throw e;}`. Or better, you can create based on `domain_error` create another exception i.e., `student_final_grade_exception`and throw it.

EDIT:

Something like:

```
 try
        {
            student.finalGrade=mnHw(hwGrades);
        }
        catch (domain_error& e)
        {
              student_final_grade_exception mean_excep;
              mean_excep.addInfo("Error in calculation means...");
              mean_excep.addInfo(e.what()); 
              throw mean_excep;
        }
```

And then, you prepare your `main` to catch `student_final_grade_exception`. Of course, there is a litle bit more work to create a new exception type, but it can make possible to get more info and let the functions to only what they suppose to do as were told.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. Any recommendations for good sources with quick explanation of how to make a new exceptio type?

Comment: @neuronet Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152720/correct-way-to-inherit-from-stdexception). I used to inherit from `std::exception`, but seems to be a better pratice to it from `std::runtime_error` or `std::logic_error`.

Comment: I wonder if there is a worked out example for novices...that is pretty esoteric for someone on chapter 4 of an intro book? Maybe I should just cut my losses now and come answer this with a fully annotated example from head to toe once I have done classes....Though this link seems helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182781/creating-exceptions-c