# String building in C++ exception’s what()

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, string-building

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16188527/1503237) declares a `private static ostringstream`. Is this thread safe? If two threads throw (and catch, and log `what()`) the exception at the same time, does this work reliably? If I declare the `ostringstream` locally, like:

```
virtual const char* what() const throw()
{
    std::ostringstream cnvt.str( "" );
    cnvt << runtime_error::what() << ": " << getNumerator()
         << " / " << getDenominator();
    return cnvt.str().c_str();
}
```

Is there a drawback (memory leak, or illegal pointer)? Or is this the thread-safe way?

Comment: In your code, you return a pointer to a string that goes out of scope, and that will lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. it's not safe at all (and pretty inefficient to my taste, can be done with `std::string` alone).
in order to make it safe, declare the `ostringstream` as `thread_local`

`static thread_local ostringstream cnvt;`

also, you should make the `cnvt` output the string to some member string in order to not return a dangling pointer.

```
class DivideByZeroException: public runtime_error {
public:

  DivideByZeroException(int x, int y)
    : runtime_error( "division by zero" ), numerator( x ), denominator( y )
    {}

  virtual const char* what() const throw()
  {
    cnvt.str( "" );

    cnvt << runtime_error::what() << ": " << getNumerator()
         << " / " << getDenominator();

    error = cnvt.str();
    return error.c_str();
  } 

   /*...*/

   private:
     std::string error;
     int numerator;
     int denominator;

   static thread_local ostringstream cnvt;
};
```

also, if the exception is "divide by zero" don't you think it's a bit silly storing the denominator? it's always a zero! otherwise you wouldn't throw "division by zero" error!

and finally 0-division error is more appropriate to be derived from `std::domain_error` which related to mathematical errors.

Answer (score 1):

`what()` is the wrong place to build the string IMHO (although there are different views on this).

`std::runtime_error` already contains a string, so let's use that one.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

struct DivideByZero : std::runtime_error
{

    DivideByZero(int x, int y)
    : std::runtime_error( make_message(x,y) )
    {}

private:
    static std::string make_message(int x, int y)
    {
        return std::string("division by zero: " + std::to_string(x) + '/' + std::to_string(y));
    }

};
```